# Apache Proxy and Daphne : slow connection

Tags: django, apache, daphne

I am using Django 3.2.3, Apache and Daphne. Daphne is very slow.

I use Apache like a proxy to send the request to Daphne :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    

    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com 


    ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8001/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8001/"

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET" env=CORS
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "false" env=CORS
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/****/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/***/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I launch Daphne with the command :

```
daphne -p 8001 asgi:application
```

When I access to my website, the log of Daphne are :

```
2021-06-04 21:17:17,821 INFO     Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
2021-06-04 21:17:17,865 INFO     Added job "my_job" to job store "default"
2021-06-04 21:17:17,866 INFO     Scheduler started
2021-06-04 21:17:17,909 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8001:interface=127.0.0.1
2021-06-04 21:17:17,912 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2021-06-04 21:17:17,913 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8001:interface=127.0.0.1
2021-06-04 21:17:17,919 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8001

127.0.0.1:34650 - - [04/Jun/2021:21:18:07] "GET /fr/" 200 234920209
127.0.0.1:34698 - - [04/Jun/2021:21:18:56] "GET /fr/jsi18n/" 304 -
```

It's working, I can display the webpage but it's very very slow, 30sec +

I have no idea of what to search, where to search ...

edit ---
Maybe the problem comes from the Apache proxy but I use 127.0.0.1, I do not see why it could be slow. ping 127.0.0.1 is fast.

edit 2 ---
Using dig and nslookup on 127.0.0.1 / localhost / SERVER ADDRESS is fast.

Can you help me maybe with some ideas ? or the solution :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found.

The problem was not from apche but from my django code. I do not know exactly because I have a made a lot of tests but I think this is because the redis server was not launch.

Thank you